# how to generate runtime database in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to generate run time database (sqlite)in iphone application.How it possible?
Please help me for this query.

Comment: It is definitely possible. Can you describe your question a little more?

Comment: Are you asking how to create the table structure in an SQLite database ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sqlite3_open`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html).

If you want a more specific answer, you'll have to ask a more specific question. As currently phrased, it is far too vague.